# How to make array space given number x

Tags: java

how to make array x's digit space not doing upper while(x!=0) {x=x/10;
            ++digit;}

```
public static void main() {
    int x = 12345;
    int digit=0;
    while(x!=0) {
        x=x/10;
        ++digit;
    }
    // how to make array x's digit space not doing upper while(x!=0) {...}
    int[] array = new int[digit];
}
```

Comment: You should explain the problem more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the number of digits of an integer, one way would be to cast the integer as a string, and checking the length of the resulting string:

```
int digit = 123456; //your int
int length = ("" + digit).length(); //i.e. the length of "123456"
```